# Solely Removing the Beginning of a String

Tags: ruby, recursion

I am trying to write a function that, when given an integer x and a string, will return the string with newlines every x characters (including spaces).

This is my code so far:

```
def add_newline(len, thing)
  if thing.length <= len
    return thing
  else
    thing.scan(/.{1, 4}/)
    val = thing[0]
    # (0..len).each { |x| thing[x] = "" }
    return val + "\n" + add_newline(len, thing.to_s)
  end
end
```

I don't even know how this problem occured, it just seems magically wrong. Here is an example:

```
puts add_newline 2, "1234"

#returns:
# 1
# 24
```

I don't know how it is possible. Before I had this:

```
def add_newline(len, thing)
 if thing.length <= len
    return thing
 else
    val = thing[0..len]
    (0..len).each { |x| thing[x] = "" }
    return val + "\n" + add_newline(len, thing)
 end
end
```

That also didn't work. It returned:

```
puts add_newline 2, "1234"

#returns:
#123
#24
```

At this point, I don't know what else to try. If someone could help me out, that would be amazing. I would also prefer to keep the recursion. (Any strings entered would not be from the user just in case that affects anything.)

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: I don't know if you strictly need recursion for this, doesn't something like this work `thing.scan(/(\w{n})/).join("\n")`? being n the len argument?

Comment: The expected output would be 12\n34

Comment: Sorry, but recursion is the last approach that would come to mind as a way of solving this problem. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function:

```
def add_new_line(len, thing)
   return thing if thing.size < len || len < 1

   head, tail = [thing.slice(0..len-1), thing.slice(len..thing.size)]

   head.gsub(/^(.{#{len}})/, "\\1\n") + add_newline(len, tail)
end
```

Curious, why do you prefer a recursion? Is it because you think this can only be solved via recursion or iteration and recursion is 'more elegant'?

Because a non-recursive function is even more elegant:

```
def add_newline(len, thing)
  thing.gsub(/(.{#{len}})/, "\\1\n")
end
```

Comment: I am decently new to recursion, so I like to find all chances I can to practice it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me count the ways the desired result could be obtained. Here are a few.

```
str = 'three blind mice'
len = 3
```

**Use a regular expression**

```
str.gsub(/(.{#{len}})/, '\1\n')
  #=> "thr\\nee \\nbli\\nnd \\nmic\\ne"
```

See [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), particularly the use of *back-references*.

**Take a procedural approach: build a new string character-by-character**

```
(1..str.size).reduce('') do |s, i|
  s << str[i-1]
  s << '\n' if (i % len).zero?
  s
end
  # => "thr\\nee \\nbli\\nnd \\nmic\\ne"
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

**Stuff newlines, back to front, using [String#insert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-insert)**

```
s = str.dup
(len..len*(str.size/len)).step(len).reverse_each { |i| s.insert(i, '\n') }
s #=> "thr\\nee \\nbli\\nnd \\nmic\\ne"
```

See [Range#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-step) and [Enumerable#reverse_each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each).

**Feed each character to [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) chained to [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to create an array that is then [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-join)'d. to to form a new string**

```
str.each_char.each_slice(len).map { |a| a.size < len ? a.join : a.join << '\n' }.join
  #=> "thr\\nee \\nbli\\nnd \\nmic\\ne"
```